# How to setup the RemoteApiInstaller with Guice when running GAE apps locally?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice, remote-debugging

I wrote a [standalone client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#Configuring_Remote_API_on_the_Client) that accesses my Google App Engine app through the [Remote API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi). I am using it to troubleshoot an issue that I am facing on the live GAE environment. That works great in a standalone client e.g. a unit test.

```
String username = "<username>";
String password = "<password>";
RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions().
    server("<host>", <port>).credentials(username, password);
RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
installer.install(options);
```

But I am also using [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) to manage dependencies. **How can I install the RemoteApiInstaller in my [GuiceCreator](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GoogleAppEngine) so that all services ([datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/), [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/), etc) come from GAE but the code runs on my local dev environment?** Instead of using the remote API in a unit test, I want to setup the Remote API with the rest of my app. I want to set breakpoints in my (local) code but communicate with (remote) datastore/memcache services.

Comment: Probably, you have wrong user credentials.

Comment: By connecting to the remote GAE app I was able to confirm that the credentials are correct. When connecting to localhost [username and password do not matter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#Configuring_Remote_API_on_the_Client).